# How can I unbind (off) listening to a DOM element without effecting others listening to same event?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
 $('#el').change(function (e) {
     if (!self.m_selected)
         return;
     self._onChange(e);
 });
```

That is in multiple places (multiple instances of objects)... and in some cases I would like a single instance to stop listening to change event, BUT, other instances still need to listen.

If I just run `$('#el').off('change');`, all will stop listening, but I only want this one class instance to stop listening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save a reference to the handler function, you can remove just that one particular handler:

```
var handler = function (e) {
        if (!self.m_selected)
            return;
        self._onChange(e);
    };
$('#el').change( handler );
```

And later:

```
$("#el").off('change', handler);
```